# If Else Statement to Skip Value if populated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create an if else script to skip a record if there is a specific value in a column of the table and continue to insert records into a different table.

How do I create the script to perform this action?

```
IF EXISTS (Select * From Table A where X =1)
BEGIN
Do nothing
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO TABLE Y
SELECT * FROM TABLE Z
END
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Use a text editor? It's really not clear what you're struggling with. Your query looks syntactically correct.

Comment: Change your script to `IF NOT EXISTS(...) INSERT...`. You do not need `ELSE ` statement

Comment: It seems you have a couple of answers here which answer the question as posted. But in the comments it seems that the question you asked is not what you are trying to solve. You should post some sample data and the desired output because it is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. This would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Jeff Are you sure you've got the tables right in your question? The IF condition uses `Table A` and has nothing to do with your insert tables: `Table Y` and `Table Z`. What connects these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead, write a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE Y
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE Z
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1 From Table A where X = 1);
```

The conditional is not needed at all.

Comment: How can I make it skip a record and continue to copy values for other records?  I want the rest of the fields for the skipped record to be blank.

Comment: @Jeff What do you mean by "skip a record and continue to copy values for other records"???

Comment: @Eric, correct, skip and continue populating on the next record and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in a proc to execute, use it this way

```
create procedure usp_insert 
as
BEGIN 
declare @rowcount int = (Select count(*) From TableA where X <>'1')
Begin
if @rowcount>=1 
INSERT INTO TABLE Y
SELECT * FROM TABLE Z
end
END
```

Comment: Using EXISTS would be a bit simpler and the performance is generally better also.

Comment: @SeanLange I Agree with you

Comment: Well then changing to use EXISTS makes this almost the exact same answer and Gordon's but you stuck it inside a procedure.

Comment: @SeanLange I will let OP use the which ever he likes, i am sure he is seeing these comments, instead of pasting same code in a proc

Comment: So just to be clear, this code is not very efficient but it demonstrates the basic format of a procedure which the OP didn't ask for. ;)

Comment: So just to be clear OP gets the required output with this script, he has never mentioned about performance of the code my man, there is no point in adding the script which is already there :)

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to skip records that have a value populated in a column and to continue to populate records that do not have a value in this column.

Comment: @jeff I guess both answers will skip records where 'x<>1', if you could add sample input and output we will try and edit the script

Comment: INSERT into A
                    select * from #temp2
                    Where Not Exists (Select 1 from D WHERE Name = '1')
                        insert into B
                        select * from #temp3
                    Where Not Exists (Select 1 from D WHERE Name = '1')
                       insert into C
                        select * from #temp4
                    Where Not Exists (Select 1 from D WHERE Name = '1')

Comment: Whats wrong with that query, it is still unclear. Please add sample source data to the main body of question